# Passing parameters as path variables in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, rails-routing

I'm still new to ROR, so pardon the simplicity of the question...

So http://www.example.com/controller/:id displays a record in my table, with :id being a number (1,2,3 etc.).

Is there a way I can have :id in the URL be the value of a field in the displayed record?  Such that I can have http://www.example.com/controller/record_field?  I want to have a human-friendly reference to specific records in my table. I'm sure this must be possible. Do I change something in routes.rb?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cleanest way is to add a new find method in your model (or simply use the find_by_fieldname Rails gives you in your control).  Then you'll have your controller use that method instead of the regular find(params[:id]) to pull your model record.

Check out Ryan B's screencast on this [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/63-model-name-in-url).  It's pretty easy, and he's a good teacher, so you shouldn't have any problems.

Answer (score 0):

I use the excellent rails plugin named friendly_id.

http://github.com/norman/friendly_id/tree/master

That should sort you out nicely. It is well documented too.

Take care around fields that might have modern Greek characters—might need to figure a work around for those.

Answer (score 0):

Jon Smock's solution will work, too.  I tend to prefer the following.

```
class Hamburger << ActiveRecord::Base

  #this normally defaults to id
  def to_param 
     name
  end

end

class SomeModelController << ApplicationController

  def show 
    @hamburger = Hamburger.find(params[:id])  #still default code
  end
end

#goes in some view
This is the <%= link_to "tastiest hamburger ever", url_for(@hamburger) %>.
```

This is, loosely speaking, an SEO technique (beautiful URLs are also user-friendly and I suggest them to absolutely everyone even if you don't care about SEO, for example on pages behind a login).  I have a more extended discussion of Rails SEO, which includes other tips like this, [here](http://www.bingocardcreator.com/rails-seo-tips.htm).

**Important tip:** You should consider, at design-time, what you are going to do if the `param` should change.  For example, in my hamburger scenario, it is entirely possible that I might rename "Sinfully Delicious Cheeseburger" to "Triple Bypass".  If that changes URLs, there are some possible implications, such as breakage of customer links to my website.  Accordingly, for production use I usually give these models an immutable `permalink` attribute which I initialize to be human-meaningful *exactly once*.  If the object later changes, oh well, the URL stays the same.  (There are other solutions -- that is just the easiest one.)